# how to make a product code list using csv and pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm new to pandas and
I have a csv file, which looks like this, but with 1.000 lines:

```
     type       size    obs      code
0    inox       1        hard
1    inox       2        soft
2    inox       4        soft2
3    gold       4        hard
4    silver     1        hard
5    gold       2        hard
```

I want the code to identify who it is
stainless steel, gold and silver, if it is soft, hard etc, and then sequence stainless steel, sequence gold.

```
   inox code 01 |
   gold code 02 |
   silver code 03 |
   hard 001 |
   soft 002 |
   soft2 003 |
```

I didn't find anything on the web not even here on stackoverflow,
the exit I need:

```
        type       size     obs      code
   0    inox       1        hard     01.001.01
   1    inox       2        soft     01.002.02
   2    inox       4        soft2    01.003.03
   3    gold       4        hard     02.001.01
   4    gold       1        hard     02.001.02
   5    silver     2        soft     03.002.01
```

Could I use pandas.loc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` and `cumcount`

```
  df['type'].map({'inox': '01', 'gold': '02', 'silver': '03'})  \
+ '.' \
+ df['obs'].map({'hard': '001', 'soft': '002', 'soft2': '003'}) \
+ '.0' \
+ df.groupby(['type']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

---

```
0    01.001.01
1    01.002.02
2    01.003.03
3    02.001.01
4    03.001.01
5    02.001.02
dtype: object
```

Comment: @PedroZ You can adjust the number of zeros in the `map` and by adding `+ '000'`